# Script to check where a email is delivered

Tags: php, jquery, curl

I'm looking for a php script to check where a email is delivered in Inbox or spam. Actually I have a mailing system now I just want to check that mail sent by me is delivered in recipients inbox or spam folder.

Comment: There is no way to discover this. Would be nice, but not (in the general case) possible.

Answer (score 1):

No this is not possible. When the mail leaves the MTA you cannot guess what will happen. Except when the target mail server reject the mail in a public way and don't just discard it.

There is a mail header for a read confimation, but not all Mail clients support it and I persoally never send them.